# Find $g'(3)$ if $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> if $f(3)=-2$ and $f'(3)=5$, find $g'(3)$ if,
>   $g(x)=3x^2-5f(x)$

the answer is -7,
I find that very hard to understand the question.
thanks

Comment: $g(x) = 3x^2 - 5f(x)$ if you derive this expression wrt $x$, you get $g'(x) = 6x - 5f'(x)$ (assuming everything is nice and differentiable). Plugging the numbers yields the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g'(x)=6*x-5*f'(x)$

$g'(3)=6*3-5*f'(3)$=$18-25=-7$
i hope it would help you

Comment: good lucks @Sb Sangpi

Comment: sorry 4 another question,i did this another question $\frac{3x+1}{f(x)}$ it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

- $(\alpha+\beta)\ '=\alpha\ '+\beta\ '$
- $f$ is differentiable at $x=3$  as $f\ '(3)$ exists.
- $f(3)$ is not a relevant piece of information here...

Comment: sorry 4 another question,i did this another question $\frac{3x+1}{f(x)}$ it doesn't work. can u help? thx

Comment: @SbSangpi The key is quotient rule for taking derivatives--One hint  is that you _need_ the information about $f(3)$...Please try this out on your own. If you still have difficulties--ping me back here. Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a homework question here are some tips.

1. Are $f,g$ differentiable functions everywhere??If not, how can you find the derivative of $g$ at a specific point (in our case 3).
2. Find everything needed for calculating $g'(3)$ from the equation given.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the problem comes from the fact that differentiation is a linear operator. This means that $(cf(x) + dg(x))' = cf'(x) + dg'(x)$ where $c$ and $d$ are constants. Assuming we know this and the differentiation rule for powers ($(x^n)' = n x^{n-1}$) we can continue by differentiating the equation
$$g(x) = 3x^2 - 5f(x)$$
to get
$$g'(x) = 6x - 5f'(x).$$

Therefore $g'(3) = 6\cdot 3 - 5 f'(3) = 18 - 5 \cdot 5 = 18 - 25 = -7$.